# Visual Studio 2010 - Change exe file names on dependent projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have two projects in VS2010. First one is a GUI that depends on second one that has DLLs.
I did a mistake in not naming them properly.

Now I want to change the name of both, I could change the name/dll name on second project by changing the assembly. But when I change assembly on first one, it doesn't work. Compilation fails. How do I change the exe name/original file name for both?

ActionLog is my first project for GUI, I am trying to rename it to ActionLog1. Just for test now. GUI defined with xml.

```
    ------ Build started: Project: ActionLog, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
C:\Users\admin\Proj\project-7440\ActionLog\MainWindow.xaml.cs(24,13): error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
C:\Users\admin\Proj\project-7440\ActionLog\MainWindow.xaml.cs(26,18): error CS1061: 'ActionLog.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'SearchBox' and no extension method 'SearchBox' accepting a first argument of type 'ActionLog.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Users\admin\Proj\project-7440\ActionLog\MainWindow.xaml.cs(27,18): error CS1061: 'ActionLog.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'AllContacts' and no extension method 'AllContacts' accepting a first argument of type 'ActionLog.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Users\admin\Proj\project-7440\ActionLog\MainWindow.xaml.cs(74,91): error CS1061: 'ActionLog.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'SearchBox' and no extension method 'SearchBox' accepting a first argument of type 'ActionLog.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Users\admin\Proj\project-7440\ActionLog\MainWindow.xaml.cs(89,13): error CS0103: The name 'ContactsList' does not exist in the current context
C:\Users\admin\Proj\project-7440\ActionLog\MainWindow.xaml.cs(97,17): error CS0103: The name 'ContactsList' does not exist in the current context
C:\Users\admin\Proj\project-7440\ActionLog\MainWindow.xaml.cs(121,13): error CS0103: The name 'ButtonClose' does not exist in the current context
C:\Users\admin\Proj\project-7440\ActionLog\MainWindow.xaml.cs(126,13): error CS0103: The name 'ButtonClose' does not exist in the current context
c:\Users\admin\Proj\project-7440\ActionLog\MainWindow.xaml(240,134): error CS1061: 'ActionLog1.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown' and no extension method 'Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown' accepting a first argument of type 'ActionLog1.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\Users\admin\Proj\project-7440\ActionLog\MainWindow.xaml(241,134): error CS1061: 'ActionLog1.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown' and no extension method 'Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown' accepting a first argument of type 'ActionLog1.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\Users\admin\Proj\project-7440\ActionLog\MainWindow.xaml(242,107): error CS1061: 'ActionLog1.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'ButtonClose_MouseLeftButtonDown' and no extension method 'ButtonClose_MouseLeftButtonDown' accepting a first argument of type 'ActionLog1.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\Users\admin\Proj\project-7440\ActionLog\MainWindow.xaml(242,92): error CS1061: 'ActionLog1.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'ButtonClose_MouseEnter' and no extension method 'ButtonClose_MouseEnter' accepting a first argument of type 'ActionLog1.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\Users\admin\Proj\project-7440\ActionLog\MainWindow.xaml(242,92): error CS1061: 'ActionLog1.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'ButtonClose_MouseLeave' and no extension method 'ButtonClose_MouseLeave' accepting a first argument of type 'ActionLog1.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\Users\admin\Proj\project-7440\ActionLog\MainWindow.xaml(244,131): error CS1061: 'ActionLog1.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown' and no extension method 'Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown' accepting a first argument of type 'ActionLog1.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Compile complete -- 14 errors, 0 warnings
```

Comment: 'Compilation fails' is a bit vague. What is the exact error message?

Comment: @Steve Give me 2, will add the actual error log and some code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I exactly understand your situation, but here is a strategy to follow:

Before you start, though, make sure you **back up your whole solution**! (Or better yet, use version control.)

Work on your dependent project first:

1. Rename the project.
2. Go to Properties/Application and rename the "Assembly name" and "Default namespace" to match your project name.
3. Do a find/replace for your whole project, replacing all instances of your original namespace with your new namespace (use "whole words only" and "match case" to be safe).
4. Compile.

Now work on your GUI project:

1. Locate the reference to your original dependent project in the References folder and remove it.
2. Rename the project.
3. Go to Properties/Application and rename the "Assembly name" and "Default namespace" to match your project name.
4. Right-click the References folder and re-add the reference to your renamed dependent project.
5. Do two find/replace operations for your whole project:

   - The first should replace the namespace for your dependent project with the new namespace.
   - The second should replace the namespace for your GUI project with the new namespace.
6. Compile.

Comment: Tried this still has issues. Why would is error out on `InitializeComponent()`? `error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: It sounds like you have a UserControl or Window that has a namespace issue or is missing InitializeComponent in the Code Behind. Perhaps one of your classes got accidentally renamed when you did find/replace to correct your namespaces? The class name needs to match the name in the Window/UserControl's `x:Class` declaration.